# python xml remove grandchildren or grandgrandchildren

Tags: python, xml, removechild

I've been googling for removing grandchildren from an xml file. However, I've found no perfect solution.
Here's my case:

```
<tree>
    <category title="Item 1">item 1 text
        <subitem title="subitem1">subitem1 text</subitem>
        <subitem title="subitem2">subitem2 text</subitem>
    </category>

    <category title="Item 2">item 2 text
        <subitem title="subitem21">subitem21 text</subitem>
        <subitem title="subitem22">subitem22 text</subitem>
            <subsubitem title="subsubitem211">subsubitem211 text</subsubitem>
    </category>
</tree>
```

In some cases, I want to remove `subitem`s. In other cases, I want to remove `subsubitem`. I know I can do like this in current given content:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(given_content)
# case 1
for item in root.getiterator():
    for subitem in item:
        item.remove(subitem)

# case 2
for item in root.getiterator():
    for subitem in item:
        for subsubitem in subitem:
            subitem.remove(subsubitem)
```

I can write in this style **only** when I know the depth of the target node. If I only know the tag name of node I want to remove, how should I implement it?
pseudo-code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for item in root.getiterator():
    if item.tag == 'subsubitem' or item.tag == 'subitem':
        # remove item
```

If I do `root.remove(item)`, it will certainly return an error because item is not a direct child of `root`.

Edited:
   I cannot install any 3rd-party-lib, so I have to solve this with `xml`.

Comment: Do I correctly understand the question text to mean that you *don't* actually care about whether something is grandchild or greatgrandchild, but only about its tag, in making the determination?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, you are right. Find the node with target name and remove it, regardless of the depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this work for me only on `xml` lib by writing a recursive function.

```
def recursive_xml(root):
    if root.getchildren() is not None:
        for child in root.getchildren():
            if child.tag == 'subitem' or child.tag == 'subsubitem':
                root.remove(child)
            else:
                recursive_xml(child)
```

By doing so, the function will iterate every node in ET and remove my target nodes.

```
test_xml = r'''
<test>
    <test1>
        <test2>
            <test3>
            </test3>
            <subsubitem>
            </subsubitem>
        </test2>
        <subitem>
        </subitem>
        <nothing_matters>
        </nothing_matters>
    </test1>
</test>
'''
root = ET.fromstring(test_xml)
recursive_xml(root)
```

Hope this helps someone has restricted requirements like me....

Answer (score 1):

To remove instances of `subsubitem` or `subitem`, no matter what their depth, consider the following example (with the caveat that it uses [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/) rather than upstream ElementTree):

```
import lxml.etree as etree

el = etree.fromstring('<root><item><subitem><subsubitem/></subitem></item></root>')
for child in el.xpath('.//subsubitem | .//subitem'):
  child.getparent().remove(child)
```

Comment: Thank you Charles, this works for most cases. However, it requires installing `lxml`. I'm working on a large amount of machines so I have to stick on xml library...

Comment: Have you tried `el.iter('subitem')` and `el.iter('subsubitem')`? I don't make a habit of using upstream ElementTree, but would expect them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Python 3.10 since getchildren() does not exist anymore:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file

> Note that concurrent modification while iterating can lead to
> problems, just like when iterating and modifying Python lists or
> dicts.

This script will work on 3.10:

```py
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
    def print_xmltree(root):
        xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", method="xml")
        print(xmlstr.decode("utf-8"))
    
    def recursive_xml(parent, depth):
        #print(depth * "  ", parent.findall('./'))
        for child in parent.findall('./'):
            if child.tag == 'subitem' or child.tag == 'subsubitem':
                parent.remove(child)
            else:
                recursive_xml(child, depth + 1)
                    
    xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tree>
        <category title="Item 1">item 1 text
            <subitem title="subitem1">subitem11 text</subitem>
            <subitem title="subitem2">subitem12 text</subitem>
            <sibetum title="subitem3">subitem13 text</sibetum>
                <subsubitem title="subsubitem1">subsubitem211 text</subsubitem>
        </category>
        <category title="Item 2">item 2 text
            <subitem title="subitem1">subitem21 text</subitem>
            <subitem title="subitem2">subitem22 text</subitem>
                <subsubitem title="subsubitem1">subsubitem211 text</subsubitem>
                <sobsobitem title="subsubitem2">wrong tag</sobsobitem>
        </category>
        <category title="Item 3">item 3 text
        </category>
    </tree>"""    
    
    #root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot() # from file
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_data) # from variable
    
    recursive_xml(root, 0)
    print_xmltree(root)
    # Note that sobsobitem was forced up in hierachy and that parent tag for subsubitem did not matter (sibetum).
    
    wait = input("Press Enter to Exit.")
```

This will output:

```xml
<tree>
    <category title="Item 1">item 1 text
        <sibetum title="subitem3">subitem13 text</sibetum>
            </category>
    <category title="Item 2">item 2 text
        <sobsobitem title="subsubitem2">wrong tag</sobsobitem>
    </category>
    <category title="Item 3">item 3 text
    </category>
</tree>
```